# Spring Security in web app deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security

I'm a beginner in spring security and I'm trying to create a simple RestConstroller that uses Ldap authentication. My application has the following structure

- springapplication-servlet.xml (dispatcher)
- application-context.xml (root context)
- web.xml
  * loads the  with application-context
  * defines dispatcher servlet to url mapping /summary
- RestController with RequestMapping /summary
- SpringConfig using @Configuration @EnableWebSecurity annotation and extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter where I declared the authorization using

  http.csrf().disable();
  http.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/summary").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()

and ldap authentication

I'm running the app using Tomcat 8 & Java 8 and I'm getting an error that says
'springSecurityFilterChain' not found
and

One solution that I've tried was trying to define the filter security but the error persists and throws bean not found together with
'Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.'

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/summary</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Most of the examples that I find online are using spring-boot app, I would need a solution for my app using Tomcat

Thank you,
any help is appreciated

As suggested in the comments, I've added web.xml snippet

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> /WEB-INF/application-context.xml </param-value> </context-param>
```

also application-context snippet

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>

    <util:properties id="myProperties" location="classpath:myProps.properties"/>
```

Comment: add jar to classpath

Comment: You need a `ContextLoaderListener` that loads the `application-context.xml` and that should also contain your security beans/configuration. That shouldn't be in `springapplication-servlet.xml` which should be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. my web.xml contains the following info <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
    
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
           
        </param-value>
 </context-param>, I have the ContextLoaderListener defined

Comment: @ScaryWombat what do you mean? I have all the jars in place